# Issue: Safari on macOS won't open a new window via keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, safari

I can open a new window from the menu bar, but for some reason Safari insists on opening a new tab rather than a new window when using either the default keyboard shortcut or a custom shortcut.

Has anyone run into this issue before? If so, how did you fix it?

Note: I have quit the application multiple times and restarted the computer.

Comment: You're not running the developer beta are you? Some stuff related to this behaviour has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLUTION:

> "There is a setting in System Preferences > Dock called "Prefer tabs when opening documents". Change this to "Manually"..."
> (Solution via [Stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41712141/2350857))

Comment: No worries at all, and welcome to stack overflow. :)

Comment: This option has been moved to General > Prefer tabs, then select "never". It will automatically update your Safari shortcut to ⌘ N instead of ⌥⌘ N

Answer (score 1):

In full screen mode, Cmd-N opens a new Tab instead of a new Window. Are you in full screen mode?

Also, in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts you can adjust the Cmd-N shortcut to open a new tab.

And it wouldn't surprise me if there is a hidden `defaults write` command to do the same, though I wouldn't know off the top of my head.

Comment: Definitely not in fullscreen mode, tried both the default keyboard shortcut and a custom keyboard shortcut, and I am running an up-to-date version of Catalina (made sure there wasn't an update before I posted the question).It was working just fine until today.

Comment: @Cabana0309 do you have any extensions?

Comment: I do, but even with them disabled and starting my computer in Safe Mode the issue persists.

Comment: Figured it out! Posting the answer now.